# Trying to implement Pushwoosh on PhoneGap build (Android)

Tags: android, push-notification, phonegap-build

I am trying to get my notifications to work however I am not receiving them. I followed the tutorial for implementing pushwoosh on phonegap build. I have my App ID and API Key from Google however I am not getting my device which the app is on to register when I reinstall the app.

I am guessing that my issue is in the following code:

```
// handle GCM notifications for Android
 function onNotificationGCM(e) {
 switch( e.event )
 {
     case 'registered':
     if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
     {
         // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
         // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
         PushWoosh.appCode = "YOUR_PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID"; // my pushwoosh id is here
         PushWoosh.register(e.regid, function(data) {
                     alert("PushWoosh register success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                 }, function(errorregistration) {
                     alert("Couldn't register with PushWoosh" +  errorregistration);
                 });

     }
     break;
```

I inserted this code in `<script>` tags within my index file however the device doesn't register what could be causing this issue?

I should also mention that I have the pushwoosh.js file within my javascript folder and I am pointing to it in my reference tags for `.js` files